# WPF Combobox w/ Observable Collection in Composite Collection

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, compositecollection

I'm trying to populate a combobox with an observable collection and a header row using a composite collection. The header is there but I can't get the OC objects to populate. I'm just starting to use OC's so might be something basic I'm missing.

Customer class:

```
public class Customer : ViewModelBaseMain
{
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
}
```

I populate the OC, which is a dependency property, from a datatable (I verified that the OC is being populated correctly):

```
ObservableCollection<Customer> dpCustomerListOC = new ObservableCollection<Customer>();
foreach (DataRow drow in dpHeaderCustTable.Rows)
{
    Customer Customer = new Customer();
    Customer.CustomerId = Convert.ToInt32(drow["customer_id"]);
    Customer.CustomerName = drow["customer_name"].ToString();
    dpCustomerListOC.Add(Customer);                            
}
```

In the usercontrol resources, I specify the VM as a static resource:

```
<local:ReservationViewModel x:Key="ReserveVM"/>
```

I've tried two different ways from posts I've read.

First way w/ collection in the resources using x:reference:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cboCustHeader" Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True" IsEditable="False"
          ItemsSource="{DynamicResource items}">                                  
     <ComboBox.Resources>
         <CompositeCollection x:Key="items">
              <ComboBoxItem IsEnabled="False">
                  <Border Style="{StaticResource ComboHeaderBorder}">
                     <Grid Style="{StaticResource ComboHeaderStyle}">
                         <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                             <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="A"/>
                             <ColumnDefinition Width="7"/>
                             <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="B"/>
                         </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                         <Grid.Children>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="ID"/>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="Name"/>
                         </Grid.Children>
                     </Grid>
                  </Border>
              </ComboBoxItem>
              <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Source={x:Reference cboCustHeader}, Path=DataContext.dpCustomerListOC}"/>
         </CompositeCollection>
     </ComboBox.Resources>                               
     <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
              <Grid>
                  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                      <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="A"/>
                      <ColumnDefinition Width="7"/>
                      <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="B"/>
                  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                  <Grid.Children>
                     <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=CustomerId, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                     <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=CustomerName, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                  </Grid.Children>
              </Grid>
          </DataTemplate>
     </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

Second way specifying the source:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cboCustHeader" Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True">
    <ComboBox.ItemsSource>
        <CompositeCollection>
            <ComboBoxItem IsEnabled="False">
               <Border Style="{StaticResource ComboHeaderBorder}">
                   <Grid Style="{StaticResource ComboHeaderStyle}">
                       <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                           <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="A"/>
                           <ColumnDefinition Width="7"/>
                           <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="B"/>
                       </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                       <Grid.Children>
                           <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="ID"/>
                           <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="Name"/>
                       </Grid.Children>
                   </Grid>
               </Border>
           </ComboBoxItem>
           <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Path=dpCustomerListOC, Source={StaticResource ReserveVM}}"/>                                                                      
      </CompositeCollection>
  </ComboBox.ItemsSource>
  <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
          <Grid>
             <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                 <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="A"/>
                 <ColumnDefinition Width="7"/>
                 <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="B"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.Children>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Path=CustomerId, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding Path=CustomerName, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
            </Grid.Children>
          </Grid>
      </DataTemplate>
  </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a public property exposing the collection on your view model:

```
public ObservableCollection<Customer> DpCustomerListOC 
{ 
    get { return dpCustomerListOC; }
}
```

And bind the combo's `ItemsSource` to it:

```
    <ComboBox x:Name="cboCustHeader" Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True">
        <ComboBox.ItemsSource>
            <CompositeCollection>
                <ComboBoxItem IsEnabled="False">
                    <Border Style="{StaticResource ComboHeaderBorder}">
                        <Grid Style="{StaticResource ComboHeaderStyle}">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="A"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="7"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="B"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Grid.Children>
                                <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="ID"/>
                                <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="Name"/>
                            </Grid.Children>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </ComboBoxItem>
                <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Path=DpCustomerListOC, Source={StaticResource ReserveVM}}"/>
            </CompositeCollection>
        </ComboBox.ItemsSource>
        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="A"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="7"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="B"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.Children>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Path=CustomerId, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding Path=CustomerName, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                    </Grid.Children>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ComboBox>
```

Make sure the collection is populated in the constructor.

Comment: I already have the public property, just didn't add it to the post (sorry). For the ItemsSource, I need to use the composite collection to add a header, but to eliminate that factor for now I took that out and tried it just as you have it and it still doesn't work. Must be missing something else...

Comment: I replicated it on my box and it works. When do you populate the collection? In the constructor? Make sure there's only one instance of your view model.

Comment: A method is called from the VM constructor which populates it. But there were 2 instances of the view model though, one I created in code behind to reference the VM and this static resource one. So how do I have 1 instance that I can use in both places? Seems like it's needed in the XAML.

Comment: I found out how to have 1 instance of the VM:

Comment: I found out how to have 1 instance of the VM: Declare it with a key
in XAML resources and access it from code behind using the "ReserveVM" key:
ReservationVM = (ReservationViewModel)Resources["ReserveVM"]; And only one instance of the VM is created. But still doesn't get the OC objects in the combobox...

Comment: Found the problem -- I had inadvertently declared a separate instance of the OC where I was creating & populating it in a method. So it went out of scope and was null. Argh! Anyway, I learned several things as I tried to find the problem. Since Bartosz pointed out one of those mistakes, I'll make his as the answer. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Other way to have a single VM is to instantiate and assign it to the DataContext property in code behind in the constructor of the Window.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are missing to NotifyPropertyChange. When working with ComboBoxs I usually just do something like this:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Customers, Mode=OneWay}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCustomer, Mode=TwoWay}"> </ComboBox>
```

Then in your class:

```
public type Customers
{
    get{return _Customers} 
    set{_SelectedCustomer = value; 
        NotifyPropertyChanged("Customers");}
}

public type SelectedCustomer
{
    get{return _SelectedCustomer;} 
    set{_SelectedCustomer = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("SelectedCustomer")}
}
```

The syntax may be off a little bit but something like this should populate the ComboBox.